# C: passing address of pointer vs passing address of array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This was an remote coding test I got a few days ago, and I've already submitted the answers so I'm not cheating here.

The question is fairly simple: implement a function to delete an item from a linked list. But with one catch: the linked list is in the form of an array.

```
typedef struct _Node{
    int val;
    struct _Node* next;
} Node;
```

Test input provided by the interviewer, which we can modify slightly

```
void printLL(Node* root){
    Node* current = root;
    while (current){
        printf("%d\n", current->val);
        current = current->next; 
    }
}

int main(){
   Node list[6];
   list[0].value =1; list[0].next = list+1;
   list[1].value =2; list[1].next = list+2;
   list[2].value =3; list[2].next = list+3;
   list[3].value =4; list[3].next = list+4;
   list[4].value =5; list[4].next = list+5;
   list[5].value =6; list[5].next = 0;

   delete(&list, 3) // this gives segmentation error with my implementation;
   printLL(list);
   return 0;
}
```

My answer, which is standard for linked list deletion:

```
void delete(Node** root, int val){
    Node* current = *root;
    Node* prev = NULL;

    if ((*root)->val == val){
        *root = (*root)->next;
        //free(current); // test case not dynamically allocated
        return;
    }
    while (current && (current->val != val)){
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
     }
    if (!current){
       printf("value not found\n");
       return ;
     }
    else{
       prev->next = current->next;
       //free(current);
    }
}
```

However, if I use pointers instead, then the function works

```
 Node* p = list;
 delete(&p, 3);
```

I think I understand the difference between &list and &p as function argument:

```
**Variable name  |  Variable value      |     Variable address**

list             | address of first elem |     address of first elem

p                | address of first elem | some random address of the pointer
```

But since in the delete function we are operating with *list and *p respectively, their value should also be the same.

My guess now is because of in

```
   *root = (*root)->next;
```

if *root is an array name, then it's illegal as we cannot reassign it. But if *root is a pointer, then we are freely to reassign them. Am I correct on this?

Thank you for reading through this long and messy post.

Comment: You're trying to use a pointer as a different type of pointer. That rarely goes well.

Comment: @RohitMourya: Something like `int **` is not a 2D array, nor can it point to one! It is a completely different datastructure.

Comment: @Olaf Yes I agree but in this case OP has created list[] and each index acts as a list in itself.

Comment: @RohitMourya: **NO**. This is a pointer, not an array! Different type and properties! An `int **`can point to an array of **pointers**, Each of these pointers **can** point to the first element of another array itself.But such _jagged arrays are completely different from a 2D array! Just because you can use the index-operator on both does not make them even related! Please refrain from telling this to beginners; there is already enough confusion about pointers and arrays, see other questions. And the question uses a 1D array of structs` which is even more different.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah. I agree.